# resizing a jpg url from Amazon Cloud to fit in my Claris pro 19 web portal

Tags: image-resizing

I'm using Claris Pro 19
I want to pull jpgs in from our Amazon cloud, I have the URL to associate with it, but I'm having trouble resizing the photo to the Web portal on Filemaker Claris. the photos come in gigantic.
Can you help..

Answer (score 0):

Filemaker cannot actually resize images natively (that is unless you can write javascript or PHP functions and call them through webviewer or Insert from URL script step).

The best way would be to use a plugin. The sample for MonkeyBreadSoftware plugin would be as follows:

```
#Allow user abort / Set error capture
#-
Set Error Capture [ On ]
Allow User Abort [ Off ]
#-
Set Variable [ $image; Value:Get ( ScriptParameter ) ]
#-
#Load image
Set Variable [ $img; Value:MBS("GMImage.NewFromContainer"; $image) ]
If [ MBS("Iserror") ]
    If [ Get ( LayoutName ) = "NarocilniceLineItems" ]
        Close Window [ Current Window ]
    End If
    Show Custom Dialog [ Message: "error” ]
    Exit Script [ ]
End If
#Scale?
Set Variable [ $ScaleWidth; Value:GetAsNumber(640) ]
Set Variable [ $ScaleHeight; Value:GetAsNumber(640) ]
Set Variable [ $DoScale; Value:0 ]
If [ $ScaleWidth > 0 ]
    If [ $ScaleHeight > 0 ]
        Set Variable [ $Scale; Value:GetAsText($ScaleWidth) & "x" & GetAsText($ScaleHeight)]
    Else
        Set Variable [ $Scale; Value:GetAsText($ScaleWidth)]
    End If
    Set Variable [ $r; Value:MBS( "GMImage.Scale"; $img; $Scale ) ]
End If
#Clear profiles
Set Variable [ $r; Value:MBS( "GMImage.SetICCColorProfile"; $img; "" ) ]
Set Variable [ $r; Value:MBS( "GMImage.Setprofile"; $img; "IPTC"; "" ) ]
Set Variable [ $r; Value:MBS( "GMImage.Setprofile"; $img; "ICM"; "" ) ]
#query size
Set Variable [ $dest_width; Value:MBS( "GMImage.GetWidth"; $img) ]
Set Variable [ $dest_height; Value:MBS( "GMImage.GetHeight"; $img) ]
#For JPEG make a copy without alpha channel
Set Variable [ $secondImage; Value:MBS( "GMImage.New"; $dest_width & "x" & $dest_height; "white" ) ]
#6 = RGB without alpha
Set Variable [ $r; Value:MBS( "GMImage.SetType"; $secondImage; 6 )]
Set Variable [ $r; Value:MBS( "GMImage.CompositeXY"; $secondImage; $img; 0; 0; 1 ) ]
#JPEG with RGB
#70% quality
Set Variable [ $r; Value:MBS( "GMImage.SetQuality"; $secondImage; 70 ) ]
Set Variable [ $final_image; Value:$secondImage ]
#Cleanup
Set Variable [ $r; Value:MBS("GMImage.Destroy"; $img) ]
Exit Script [ Result: $final_image ]
```

This is printed sample of a script I use with the mentioned plugin to reduce the size of images. It should work as long as images get stored in a container and passed into the script as parameter.
I hope this helps you somewhat.